How to highlight 1 cell in calendar?
I need to highlight my birthday but cell (29) is getting out of table alignment. How to highlight a day without affecting the table alignment?
$day_num = 1;
$day_num_birthday = 26;
$birth_month =  7;
if ($month==$birth_month)
{
    while ($day_num <= $days_in_month)
    {
        if ($day_num==$day_num_birthday)
        {
            echo '<td bgcolor= "red">' . $day_num. '</td>';
        }
        if ($day_num == $day_num_birthday)
        {
            $day_num++;
            continue;
        }
        echo '<td >' . $day_num. '</td>';
        $day_num++;
        $day_count++;
        if ($day_count > 7) 
        {
            echo '</tr><tr>';
            $day_count = 1;
        }
    }
}

Here is an image of the calendar:
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/VCVan.png

Improve your code
                    $day_num = 1;
                    $day_num_birthday = 26;
                    $birth_month =  7;
                    
                    if ($month==$birth_month)
                    {
                        while ($day_num <= $days_in_month)
                        {
                            if ($day_num==$day_num_birthday)
                            {
                                echo '<td bgcolor= "red">' . $day_num. '</td>';
                            }else {
                                echo '<td >' . $day_num. '</td>';
                            }
                            
                            $day_num++;
                            $day_count++;
                            
                            if ($day_count > 7) 
                            {
                                echo '</tr><tr>';
                                $day_count = 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }

Output:


thank you it works!

@xxx You're most welcome
